# add_meta_box does not display meta box in Admin

Tags: plugin-development, custom-field, metabox

I have two wordpress sites:

1. running on localhost server (PHP7.3)
2. hosted on Bluehost.com (PHP7.2)

The metabox gets added on my local website, but the same piece of code does not work on bluehosted website.

What is wrong?

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_mu_address_meta_box' );

function add_mu_address_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'your_fields_meta_box', // $id
        'mu Address', // $title
        'show_mu_address_meta_box', // $callback
        'post', // $screen
        'advanced', // $context
        'high' // $priority
    );
}



function show_mb_address_meta_box() {
    global $post;  
        $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'your_fields', true ); ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="your_meta_box_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( basename(__FILE__) ); ?>">

            <?php }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_mu_address_meta_box' );

function add_mu_address_meta_box() {
$screens = array( 'post', 'page' );
    add_meta_box(
        'your_fields_meta_box','mu Address','show_mb_address_meta_box',$screens,'advanced','high' 
    );
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are generally not useful to future visitors. Can you please [edit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/344838/edit) your answer to explain how it solves the users question? Thank you.